# How to close a window if tk.Toplevel is in a different file

Tags: python, tkinter

how do I close my current window if I can't see the tk.Toplevel(root) from the method I am in?

Here a small example of what i mean:

file1.py:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import file2
class ExampleMain:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.mainFrame = tk.Frame(root)
        ...
        tk.Button(self.mainFrame, command=self.button_pressed)
        ...

    def button_pressed(self):
        self.whatever = tk.Toplevel(root)
        self.app = file2.ExampleNotMain(self.whatever)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = ExampleMain(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

file2.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
class ExampleNotMain:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(root)
        ...
        tk.Button(self.frame, command=self.close_window)
        ...

    def close_window(self):
        =>  missing_command_here
```

In this example I would like to close the second window created (and keep the first).

If all the code is in one file something like

```
self.whatever.destroy()
```

would do it. My problem is I can't see the object from the first file with the command being in the second file.

I found something like

```
execfile("file2.py")
```

but I don't like that solution.

Is there a better way to solve my problem?

I would realy apriciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You code does not show the creation of a second, non-root Toplevel.

Comment: I counted the root as the first window and the non-root window as second. I want to close the non-root window

Comment: I see it now and will answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create ExampleNotMain, you pass the 2nd Toplevel self.whatever.  In `ExampleNotMain.__init__`, it gets bound to `root`.  (`master` or `parent` would be a better parameter name).  In `__init__`, add `self.top` = root`(or whatever you call the passed-in toplevel).  In`close_window`, add`self.top.destroy()`.